# How to log off users when screen is locked on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I was wondering if there is anyway to recognize a locked screen with PowerShell and force a logoff? The script I have below works, but not when the screen is locked.

The situation is that we have a couple of conference computers where users forget to log off and I want to run these scripts locally on those machines to check for idle times and log off idle users. Any help would be appreciated. The script I have is below.

```
$idle_timout = New-TimeSpan -minutes 1

Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

    public static class UserInput {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
            public uint cbSize;
            public int dwTime;
        }

        public static DateTime LastInput {
            get {
              DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
              DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
              return lastInput;
            }
        }

        public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
            get {
                return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
            }
        }

        public static int LastInputTicks {
            get {
                LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                return lii.dwTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

$loggedOff = 0

do
{
    $idle_time = [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime

    if (($loggedOff -eq 0) -And ($idle_time -gt $idle_timout))
    {
        shutdown.exe -l

        $loggedOff = 1
    }

    if ($idle_time -lt $idle_timout)
    {
        $loggedOff = 0
    }
}
while (1 -eq 1)
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to just use a scheduled task.  This example shuts down the machine, but I don't see any reason why you can't just call logoff.exe instead: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30758/make-your-pc-shut-down-at-night-but-only-when-youre-not-using-it/

Comment: How is this script executed in that it does not run under that circumstance? It looks like it will run indefinitely and rather frequently which looks like a bad coding choice.

Comment: Well i could do the scheduled task but would that run for every domain user on that specific computer? And i was going to add a timer on when to run the script every 20 minutes and check for ten minutes of idle time but i am running this script on my local machine for testing. But yes you are right it does run indefinitely until the action occurs. What is interesting however is that the script still runs when my screen is locked but it doesn't execute the shutdown -l.